# Put multiple filters on data from database

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, filtering, vuetify.js

I am fetching data from database.

Data is structured like this:

```
serie
   --- title (string)
   --- category (array)
```

I made search filter with computed property. It looks like this:

```
filteredSeries () {
  return this.series.filter(serie => {
    return serie.title.toLowerCase().match(this.search.toLowerCase())
  })
}
```

I am looping through series like this:

```
<v-flex xs12 sm4 md3 lg2 v-for="serie in filteredSeries" :key="serie.title" pa-3>

.....

</v-flex>
```

Search word is got from here:

```
<v-text-field label="Search" height="35" v-model="search" prepend-inner-icon="search"></v-text-field>
```

It all works just fine, but now we are getting to my problem. I want to filter series not just by title, but by category too.

I get all categories from data method in array like this:

```
data () {
  return {
    series: [],
    search: '',
    categories: [
      'Crime', 'Drama', 'Mistery', 'Comedy', 'Horror', 'Sci-Fi'
    ],
    filterCategory: []
  }
},
```

Filter select is filled with data like this:

```
<v-select  prepend-inner-icon="category" height="35" v-model="filterCategory" :items="categories" chips label="Category" multiple></v-select>
```

This select is returning filterCategory array. Now what I want is that I get series with specific categories selected in filterCategory. I don't know how to do that. I think that it would be perfect if filtering by category could be included in computed property where is filtering by search word done.

Any help how that could be done is welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your filter method can be modified to also filter by `filteredCategories`.

We can use JavaScript's [Array.every()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) and [Array.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) method to do that.

Also, I would use [String.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) instead of [String.match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match), as `match()` is mostly used when searching against a regular expression.

```
filteredSeries () {

  // Filtering by selected categories.
  const filteredSeries = this.series.filter(serie => {
    return this.filteredCategories.every(category => {
      return serie.categories.includes(category);
    });
  });

  // Further filtering by search word.
  return filteredSeries.filter(serie => {
      return serie.title.toLowerCase().includes(this.search.toLowerCase()));
  });
}
```

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear enough. I don't want to check if category includes search word. I want to get back series that have categories selected by me from `<v-select>`.

Comment: @PatrickJane - Okay, and you also want that to happen inside this `filteredSeries()` right? So that you only search on `filteredSeries` returned after applying category filter.

Comment: Well ,yeah. I want that to happen then because I don't know how else to do it.

Comment: This part here is confusing `category => category.toLowerCase() === this.search.toLowerCase()`. It checks if serie category is equal to search word. I don't need that. I need to check if selected categories from `<v-select>` element contains serie categories.

Comment: I get error `Error in render: "RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded"`. I guess it is because of 2 `.filter()`

Comment: Try my edited answer which uses `some()`. No, that wouldn't be a problem at all. Something else must be wrong. What is the code at the corresponding line number of that error? That should help in resolving this error.

Comment: `this.filteredSeries.filter`. filteredSeries is const, it is not from data method so there is no need to use `this`

Comment: I corrected that in my code but it is not showing any series. I guess computed property is returning something bad but I cant figure out what.

Comment: Can you verify again that you added this filter exactly? Also, are you still getting that stack size error? I also assumed that you have `filteredCategories` value in your code and accessing it using `this.filteredCategories`.Looks like you have `filterCategory`, not `filteredCategories`.

Comment: I am not getting stack size error any more. I have message that shows with v-if condition `filteredSeries.length == 0` and it is showing which means that filteredSeries.length == 0.

Comment: @PatrickJane - I saw that you fixed the property name. Can you add `console.log(this.filteredSeries)` before first filter and `console.log(filteredSeries)` after first filter and post your output?

Comment: It is working. Problem was because on default `filteredCategories` was empty array and it wasn't showing any series. I put condition `if (this.filteredCategories.length == 0) {
            return true
          } else {
            return this.filteredCategories.includes(category);
          }` It is working now. I think I will have more questions. Thank you for this.

Comment: That's great. I'm glad you figured it out.

Comment: For the benefit of future readers, consider marking the answer as accepted if it answered your question.

Comment: Well I still have some problems. If `filteredCategories` contains for example this `['Crime', 'Comedy']`, I want to show series which have those 2 categories and any other but I don't want to show series that have at least one of filteredCategories. So I think that solution would be that we should return true only if serie.category contains whole filteredCategories array.

Comment: I understood what you want. Check out my edited answer where I'm using `every()`. Let me know how it goes. Also, you don't need to add any `if` conditions to check if empty, `every()` method returns true for any condition put on an empty array.

Comment: But I need to check if `serie.category` contains `filteredCategories`, not if `filteredCategories` contains `serie.category`.

Comment: Yes, in this case both are the same. With `every()`, you are essentially saying every category in filtered categories must be present in serie category, which is exactly what you want. Check out the documentation for [every()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) for more info.

Comment: Yeah, it is working perfectly. I would like to congratulate to you. You just made my day. Hope you are proud of yourself, you just did such a great job. BIG THANK YOU. Hope that you will help me with any other problem on stackoverflow :D. Cheers mate.

Comment: Thank you. Happy to help. I'm glad it is working. Cheers :)